"Cannot use import statement outside a module" in Vue-Cli+electron+electron-builder
I'm using Vue3(use vue cli to init), typescript, and electron-builder to develop a simple electron app. The npm run electron:serve works correctly. I successfully export the .exe file, but when I executed the app, I faced an error: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
error-pic
I know there're already a lot of people asking this issue. But the error persisted after  I trying their solutions. E.g, when I use 'commonjs' for "module" and "type", my app didn't work correctly(missing some components, background pictures and vurtify UIs).
My codes (the version that could work correctly in "npm run electron:serve"):

tsconfig.json:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
, "src/utils/storage.js"  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}


package.json

{
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.nyyj.frontend",
    "copyright": "KW",
    "author": "Kevin",
    "productName":"南雍易记",
    "icon": "src/assets/icon.png",
    "electronDownload": {
      "mirror": "https://npmmirror.com/mirrors/electron/"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "portable"
      ]
    }
  },
  "name": "nyyj-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "output": "npx electron-builder",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "src/background.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "ts-loader": "~8.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "electron": "^33.2.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}


background.ts (part of)

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: (process.env
          .ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION as unknown) as boolean,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'), // 添加 preload.ts 文件的路径
    },
    title: '南雍易记',
  })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL as string)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
  win.setMinimumSize(1200, 800)
}

Thank a lot for any help in advance.

btw, I use npx electron-builder to build, for "electron:build" had a lot of errors.
